# Solving parse() error in Rust for beginners

Tags: rust, error-handling, rust-cargo

this is my code. It takes a number and then panicks.

Code:

```rust
//Convert temperatures between Fahrenheit and Celsius.
use std::io;

fn main() {

let c: bool = true;
  
    let f: bool = false;
    let mut temperatur = String::new();
    
    println!("Gib die Temperatur an:");
    
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut temperatur)
        .expect("Konnte nicht gelesen werden");
    
    let temperatur_int: i32 = temperatur.parse::<i32>().unwrap();
    
    println!("{}", temperatur_int);
}
```

Error:

```
Gib die Temperatur an: 5 thread 'main' panicked at 'called Result::unwrap()on anErrvalue: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }', src/main.rs:17:57 note: run withRUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display a backtrace

Tried to parse String to Integer
```

Comment: What input are you passing? The error indicates `parse` returned an `Error` value, meaning that `parse` could not convert the given value to an `i32`. For anything containing non-digit characters it will fail. See [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cf5d516b339e66366567caccea8a1668) for an example

Comment: ThoPaz's solution worked with the trim() function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing the right thing, but you forgot that you will get a newline in your string when reading from stdin. So instead of '32' you will have '32\n', which cannot be parsed.

So do [trim()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.trim) additionally before the parsing:

```
    let temperatur_int: i32 = temperatur.trim().parse::<i32>().unwrap();
```